# Date string to NSDate swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

i'm having an array fill with date string, which i would like to go through and check whether the date is today or yesterday. The date string could look like following:

```
2015-04-10 22:07:00
```

So far i've tried just to convert it using dateFormatter, but it keeps returning nil

```
    var dateString = arrayNews[0][0].date as NSString
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

    var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString as String)
    println(date)
```

the sudo code i would like to look something like this

```
if dateString == currentDate
    date = "Today, hh:mm"
else if dateString == currentDate(-1)
    date = "Yesterday, hh:mm
else
    date = dd. MM, hh:mm
```

in the else statement the date could be 1. April, 12:00

How can i achieve such a logic?

**Without the logic**

```
func getDate(dateStr:String, format:String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") -> NSString {
    var dateFmt = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    dateFmt.dateFormat = format
    let newsDate = dateFmt.dateFromString(dateStr)!

    let date = NSDate();
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()


    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone()
    let localDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)


    return ""
}
```

Comment: As others have pointed out, you want `HH`. As an aside, is this time, 22:07, i.e. 10:07pm, GMT or local time? Date formatters always assume it's local time, so I just wanted to make sure. But when saving times in persistent storage or exchanging with network service, it's prudent to include time zone information (or always store times in GMT/UTC/Zulu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`

- HH: 24h format
- hh: 12h format (with AM/PM)

Pay attention with dateFormatter, by default, it use localtime zone.
`println()` shows the value for GMT time, which is hold by NSDate.

It means, without specifying timezone, when you convert your string `2015-04-10 22:07:00` to NSDatetime, it return a data which is the time at your local time zone is **2015-04-10 22:07:00**. As `NSDate` holds date time in GMT, you will see a different value when you show the value of that `NSDate` with `println()`.

If your timezone is GMT+2 (2h earlier than GMT), when it's 22h:07 in your place, the GMT time is 20h:07. When you call `println()` on that `NSDate`, you see 2015-04-10 20:07:00

To compare 2 NSDate:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

let compareResult = calendar?.compareDate(date, toDate: date2, toUnitGranularity: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay)

if (compareResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame) {
    println("yes")
} else {
    println("no")
}
```

//to get yesterday, using NSCalendar:

```
let yesterday = calendar?.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, value: -1, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchStrictly)
```

Comment: okay this date is static and should not be changed regarding different timezone? will it do that?

Comment: Yes, the value does not change. It's in GMT. But depending on how to show the value in your application (or console), you will get different display of that date.

Comment: I've now added the code above where localdate is the timezone datetime and newsDate is the date of the news. I now want to compare these to dates without the time, how is that possible to check whether its the same date or yesterday?

Comment: to compare two NSDate, you should use NSCalendar (suppose that it's Gregorian calendar). See my updated answer